# PL/SQL Server Page cannot find form

Tags: plsql, plsql-psp

For some reason, this code does not work. It cannot find "User.ex6a1_order_receipt". However, if I type the URL in manually I can navigate to it. What am I doing wrong? This is the complete error.

> The requested URL /classpsp/User.ex6a1_order_receipt was not found on this server

```
<form action="User.ex6a1_order_receipt" method="post">
 --stuff here
</form>
```

Here is the complete code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<%@page language="PL/SQL"%>
<%@plsql procedure="ex6a1_order_sentiment"%>
<head>
<title>Order Sentiment</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center"><p><h2>Sentiment for Occasion</h2>
<a href="User.ex6a1_order_sentiment">Order Sentiment</a><br>
<hr /></div>
<br> 
<!-- Start Page Content -->
<p><b>Enter Order</b></p>
<form action="User.ex6a1_order_receipt" method="post">
<p>Sentiment ID: <input type=text name="sentiment_id_text" value="" size=5 maxlength=20></p>
<p>Quantity: <input type=text name="Quantity_text" value="" size=5 maxlength=20></p>
<p>Customer ID:<select name="CustomerFormBox_text">
<option value="103" selected>Sania Raina</option>
<option value="101">Tracey Bussell</option>
<option value="102">Lacy George</option>
<option value="104">Tom Peters</option>
<option value="105">Sharon Key</option></select></p>
<p>Payment Type: <input type=radio name="paymentTypeRadio" value="Check">Check
<input type=radio name="paymentTypeRadio_text" value="CC" checked>Credit Card</p>
<input type=reset name="ResetButton" value="Reset"/>
<input type=submit name="FormsButton1" value="Process Order"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas? I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens because the package User.ex6a1_order_receipt does not have all of the form elements specified in the procedure's parameters.

For simplicity, use flexible parameter passing:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14010/concept.htm#i1005764
http://vanbortel.blogspot.com/2006/09/modplsql-and-flexible-parameter.html

Then you can pass any number form items into the procedure without needing to change the package's parameters.

Inside of the package, use a function and turn the parameters into a associative array for easy processing.